# jQuery DataTables - width settings ignored after fnDestroy (Coffeescript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, datatables

I'm trying to make a table that will change its contents when you click the first column of any row, in a sort of "more details" way. When I first render the table it's fine, but when I render it again the width settings don't take and the table spills out to the right, ignoring the widths I set.

This is basically what my code is doing:

```
MyTable = class module.MyTable
    constructor: (@my_data) ->
        setup_table()

    setup_table: ->
        @datatable = $('#my-datatable').dataTable
            bAutoWidth: false
            bPaginate: false
            bSort: true
            bFilter: false
            bRetrieve: true
            iDisplayLength: 50
            aaData: @my_data
            aoColumns: [{
                sWidth: '200px'
                fnRender: (obj) =>
                    # do some stuff
            }, {
                sWidth: '150px'
                fnRender: (obj) =>
                    # do some other stuff
            }]
            fnRowCallback: (row, data) =>
                key = row.cells[0].firstChild.id
                $(row.cells[0].firstChild).unbind().click( () =>
                    @my_data = @get_data(key)
                    @datatable.fnDestroy()
                    @setup_table()
                )
                row

    get_data: (key) ->
        # do some stuff
```

(I realize `fnRender` is deprecated.)

The markup gets generated like so:

```
<div class="dataTables_wrapper" id="my-datatable_wrapper">
    <table id="my-datatable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="sorting_asc" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 200px;">
                    yada yada
                </th>
                <th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 150px;">
                    yada yada
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody style="display: table-row-group;">
            <tr class="odd">
                <td class="sorting_1">
                    foo
                </td>
                <td>
                    bar
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="even">
                ...and so on
            </tr>
            ... and so on
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

So... what gives? Is `fnDestroy` not doing what I think it's supposed to?

*Edit*: for what it's worth, I tried using `fnClearTable()` and `fnAddData()` too, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out (after many trials and tribulations) that the problem was that, despite what I told datatables, any text which didn't fit in the cell and couldn't wrap caused the cell to stretch. The solution, then, was to add some overflow CSS:

```
table#my-datatable td {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Since this led to cells getting cut off, I added `title`s to my cells. Well, actually, I was using [twipsy](https://github.com/Trenker/Twipsy/), but I think the equivalent in jQuery would be something like this:

```
addTitles: ->
    $('table#my-datatable td').each ->
        $cell = $(this)
        $cell.attr('title', $cell.text())
```